# Trying to join 2 different entities in different bundles, failed

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to launch a query in Symfony2 (I'm quite new), where I need to join two different entities, in different bundles:

- Candc/ComercioBundle/Entity/Venta/ItemVentaCarta And
- Candc/ProductoBundle/Entity/Producto.

They have a relation manytoone-onetomany.

```
Class Producto/////
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Candc\ComercioBundle\Venta\ItemVentaCarta", mappedBy="Producto")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

And:

```
Class ItemVentaCarta//////

    /**
     * catalog card wich is referenced.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Candc\ProductoBundle\Entity\Producto", inversedBy="ItemVentaCarta")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="carta_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */ 
    private $carta;
```

This is the query I'm launching:

```
public function findLastProducts(){
//this is what I need to do in SQL language :
            $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM c_venta_item 
                LEFT JOIN c_venta_item_carta 
                ON c_venta_item.id=c_venta_item_carta.id
                LEFT JOIN usuario ON c_venta_item.user_id = usuario.id
                LEFT JOIN producto ON c_venta_item_carta.carta_id = producto.id';
            return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery("SELECT ivc
                    FROM \Candc\ComercioBundle\Entity\Venta\ItemVentaCarta ivc
                    LEFT JOIN ivc.producto p
                    WHERE ivc.carta = p.id")
                ->getResult();
    }
```

I'm in Symfony 2.7.7 and the exception I get is that one:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 105 near 'p
> WHERE': Error: Class Candc\ComercioBundle\Entity\Venta\ItemVentaCarta has no association named producto

(I tried both producto and Producto, to avoid Typo errors)
Also searched in the forum, founded many post related, but cant solve it.

I cleared cache, and also tried a schema update, but I get a message that says:

> "there's nothing to update buddy, your db is already sync with the entity metadata"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi DQL is bound to the object properties, not the mapped entity name, please update your code by doing the following:

```
Class ItemVentaCarta//////

    /**
     * catalog card wich is referenced.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Candc\ProductoBundle\Entity\Producto", inversedBy="ItemVentaCarta")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="carta_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */ 
    private $producto; // previously $carta
```

Also, it looks like your query needs changing to:

```
SELECT ivc 
FROM \Candc\ComercioBundle\Entity\Venta\ItemVentaCarta ivc
LEFT JOIN ivc.producto p ON ivc.carta = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i did what u recommend, and the exception about the query dissapeared, im returning the result of the query i get  to the controller, and pass it to the Twig system, when i try to write a property of the entity Product ( linked to ItemVentaCarta ) like for example, the name,  i still get an exception : 

Method "nombre" for object "Candc\ComercioBundle\Entity\Venta\ItemVentaCarta" does not exist in CandcFrontendBundle:Portada:index.html.twig at line 346 

Its true that, method nombre (name), doesnt exist on ItemVentaCarta, but it does in Product, what im doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to ensure that you have a getters & setters in your entities. You will then need to get the product entity from the ItemVentaCarta entity (example: $itemVentaCarta->getProducto()->setNombre(1);)